# cURL + PHP + File Upload issues

Tags: php, ajax, curl, file-upload

Hello fellow programmers.

I am beginner programmer and I have failed attempt into creating a script for uploading image on one specific site.

My boss needs to upload images to specific site. To speed things up I need to create a script for that.

I usually use multi-part form data with cURL, but this site it is different.

Here are the headers

```
POST /upload-new.php?banner_url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com&ad_type=1&banner_size= HTTP/1.1
Host: admin.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: lv,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
X-File-Name: indonesia.gif
X-File-Size: 15450
X-File-Type: image/gif
X-File-Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 09:48:22 GMT
X-Requested-With: FileDrop-XHR-FileAPI
Referer: https://admin.domain.com/campaigns-edit.php
Content-Length: 15450
Cookie: goals=
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
GIF89a,ú
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 13 Jun 2015 16:22:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
----------------------------------------------------------
https://admin.domain.com/data/tmp-uploads/159310_20150613122208_indonesia.gif

GET /data/tmp-uploads/159310_20150613122208_indonesia.gif HTTP/1.1
Host: admin.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: lv,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://admin.domain.com/campaigns-edit.php
Cookie: goals=
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 13 Jun 2015 16:22:08 GMT
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Length: 15450
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 Jun 2015 16:22:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Etag: "557c58b0-3c5a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

This is what I tried

```
  $file = realpath($file_name);
  $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
  $mimetype = $finfo->file($file);
  $cfile = curl_file_create($file, $mimetype); 


  $PostData = array( '' => $cfile );

  //$headers

  $headers = array();

  $headers[] = 'X-File-Name: indonesia.gif';
  $headers[] = 'X-File-Size: 15450';
  $headers[] = 'X-File-Type: image/gif';
  $headers[] = 'X-File-Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 09:48:22 GMT';
  $headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: FileDrop-XHR-FileAPI';  

  $URL = "https://admin.domain.com/upload-new.php?banner_url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com&ad_type=1&banner_size="

    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
   // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$PostData); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);         


    $size = filesize($lfile);
        $file = fopen($lfile, 'r');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "@" . $lfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $size);


    If (StrLen ($Proxy) > 0)
    {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$Proxy);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);
```

Website answers with link to image which gives me 404. So seems like I am failing to send over the file.

Can anybody please give me some guidance?

Comment: Just a thought, but do you have to log into this site to be able to upload files? If so, have you actually emulated login to be able to access those pages? It stands to reason that if you're not logged in, those URLs may well be set to 404.

Comment: Yes, I was able to login successfully and kept using the same cookie file for this file upload.